# spring mvc requestmapping dynamic url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

How do I change my request mapping for dynamic urls? URLs might look like this:

- http://zz.zz.zz.com:8080/webapp/p1/q9/e3/test?Id=2&maxrows=5
- http://zz.zz.zz.com:8080/webapp/a1/b2/c3/test?Id=2&maxrows=5
- http://zz.zz.zz.com:8080/webapp/x1/y2/z3/test?Id=2&maxrows=5

Here's the working controller syntax when the url is in this format:

http://zz.zz.zz.com:8080/webapp/test?Id=2&maxrows=5

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody void test(
    @RequestParam(value = "Id", required = true) String Id,
    @RequestParam(value = "maxrows", required = true) int maxrows
) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Id: " + Id + " maxrows: " + maxrows);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}")
public @ResponseBody void test(
    @RequestParam(value = "Id", required = true) String Id,
    @RequestParam(value = "maxrows", required = true) int maxrows,
    @PathVariable(value = "param1") String param1,
    @PathVariable(value = "param2") String param2,
    @PathVariable(value = "param3") String param3) {
    ...
}
```

For more information look at [Spring Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates)