# RequestMapping Dynamic Url

Tags: spring-boot, controller, interceptor, dynamic-url, dynamic-mapping

I Have a **Spring Boot Server**, In my Database, I have some URLs without any special pattern, I want `RequestMapping` all of these stored URLs into the `Controller` and return a special view(control by template engine) for this.

I tried to do this by adding the interceptors method to my Project but I don't have any idea about returning a special view.

I read these questions:

- [Dynamic Url in @Requestmapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58969804/dynamic-url-in-requestmapping)
- [spring mvc requestmapping dynamic url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574537/spring-mvc-requestmapping-dynamic-url)
- [@RequestMapping controllers and dynamic URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879666/requestmapping-controllers-and-dynamic-urls)
- [Use @RequestMapping with Dynamic URL at Controller Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69742261/use-requestmapping-with-dynamic-url-at-controller-level)

but I don't have any special pattern in the URLs of my project and there are other URLs and controllers in my project.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search, I found the solution for defining a URL and template name in the database and dynamic URL mapping without any Controller and methods.

I have the database's table  by Name `Sample`:

**Sample**:

| field | Detail |
| --- | --- |
| `url` | address url of controller |
| `template_view_name` | address of template(html) |

I overriding the method `addViewControllers` of `WebApiConfigurer` to solve my problem:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    List<Pair<String, String>> pathTemplate = getPathWithTemplate();

    for (Pair<String, String> pt : pathTemplate) {
        registry.addViewController(pt.getKey()).setViewName(pt.getValue());
    }
}
```

complete code of `WebApiConfigurer`:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class WebApiConfigurer implements org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private CCFormCrudModelInitializer ccFormCrudModelInitializer;

    @Autowired
    private SampleRepository sampleRepository;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        //if need to add interceptors
        String[] path = getPath();

        registry.addInterceptor(new SampleInterceptor()).addPathPatterns( path );

    }


    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        List<Pair<String, String>> pathTemplate = getPathWithTemplate();

        for (Pair<String, String> pt : pathTemplate) {
            registry.addViewController(pt.getKey()).setViewName(pt.getValue());
        }
    }


    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/",
            "classpath:/resources/",
            "classpath:/static/",
            "classpath:/public/"
    };

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS)
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.HOURS));
    }


    private List<Pair<String, String>> getPathWithTemplate(){
        return sampleRepository.findAll().stream().map(m -> new Pair<>(m.getUrl(), m.getTemplateName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private String[] getPath(){
        return sampleRepository.findAll().stream().map(m -> m.getUrl()).toArray(String[]::new);
    }

}
```